# Trying to make an add-on to keep Operators somewhere where I can always use them if I need something (2.8+)

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator

Disclaimer: I know pretty much nothing about python, I'm learning as I go along. I just watched a video where someone went over the basics of python scripting in Blender, so I have some understanding of what to do, but not what to put in.

So, I'm sure we're all familiar with the Operator in the left-hand corner of Blender. If you do any other action in Blender, however, the operator for the thing you were doing before goes away, and you CANNOT get it back. Even by pressing f9. Although for some things like move, rotate, and scale, this isn't a big deal, for other things, such as the Building Tools addon, it can get really annoying, because the operator makes decisions very final if you change your mind later down the line.

Surely there has to be a way to make it so you can pin the operator panel for something, so you can access it whenever, even when doing something that makes another operator panel pop up.

Comment: You can either add a panel in the properties editor, or in the "N" panel that opens when you press N. Check out the python templates in the scripting editor : Templates > Python > Simple panel

Answer (score 1):

Certainly with 2.8 you can add things to your [Quick Favorites](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/tool_system.html#quick-favorites).  For example, here I added some basic objects, and whole "Add Mesh" list, and the Rotate operator to my Quick favorites, just by right-clicking on the menu and "Add to Quick Favorites", then re-calling with the 'q' key.  This requires no complicated python coding.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to add to what james_t posted, and say that you can add items to the *Quick Favorites* from the search menu F3 by right clicking. Also, I was searching for how to do that and found this